# Excel vba ADODB.Connection Sql Count distincts

Tags: sql, count, distinct, ado

I am trying to count distincts

```
Sub sql(sqlStr As String, PasteRnG As Range)

Dim con As Object
Dim rstData As Object
Dim sDatabaseRangeAddress As String


    Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rstData = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & ActiveWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties = ""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=yes"";"
    rstData.Open sqlStr, con

    PasteRnG.CopyFromRecordset rstData

    rstData.Close
    Set rstData = Nothing
    Set con = Nothing

End Sub
```

query

```
sql "SELECT DISTINCT `P3`,`P2`,`P1`, COUNT(DISTINCT `P3`) AS countOf FROM [QQ$]  ", Worksheets("QQQQ").Range("a3")
```

error on

```
SELECT DISTINCT `P3`,`P2`,`P1`, COUNT(DISTINCT `P3`) AS countOf FROM table;
```

But I get error on `COUNT(DISTINCT`P3`)`

I need to get in 4th column count of each DISTINCT `P3`

```
Distinctlist  P2   P1   CountOfDistinctInP3
    111 ,     11,  1,  56pcs.
    222,      22,  2,  25pcs.
```

P3 cannot be empty!!! Always have value

But this fine works like i need

```
sql "SELECT DISTINCT `P3`, COUNT(`P3`) FROM [QQ$] GROUP BY `P3` ", Worksheets("QQQQ").Range("a3")
```

But without P2 and P1 (((

---

Comment: remove `distinct` from `count()`

Comment: I would suggest using `group by` instead of distinct , but I'm not sure what is your original data and what is the expected output. An example might help.

Comment: Error You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression `P3` as part of an agregate function

Comment: What is your 4th column called? Do you want the count of all its values or all its distinct values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, every column in a SELECT that is not aggregated needs to be in the GROUP BY clause

```
sql "SELECT `P3`, `P2`, `P1`, COUNT(`P3`) FROM [QQ$] GROUP BY `P3`, `P2`, `P1` ", Worksheets("QQQQ").Range("a3")
```

Comment: The DISTINCT is redundant.

Comment: No, as I need get distincts list too

Comment: Which the GROUP BY will give you, hence the DISTINCT is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Try below Query

```
select count (select distinct p3 from table) from table
```

Comment: At most one record must be returned by this subquery

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `P3`,`P2`,`P1`, COUNT( `P3`) AS countOf FROM table group by  `P3`
```

Comment: Cannot have agregate function in GrOUP BY clause (COUNT(`P3`))

Answer (score 0):

You SQL would seem to be trying to count the number of distinct values of P3 for each combined value of P1, P2 and P3. That will only ever be 0 (if P3 is NULL) or 1. However using an aggregate function (COUNT) will result in all rows being reduced to 1 row, hence P3 could have multiple values (and so a larger count), but the values of P1 and P2 would be undefined (they could have come from any row.

What you probably want is something like this:-

```
SELECT `P2`,`P1`, COUNT(DISTINCT `P3`) AS countOf 
FROM table
GROUP BY `P2`,`P1`;
```

Or if you need a list of the values of P3

```
SELECT `P2`,`P1`, COUNT(DISTINCT `P3`) AS countOf, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT P3)
FROM table
GROUP BY `P2`,`P1`;

SELECT `P3`, `P2`,`P1`, COUNT(`P3`) AS countOf, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT P3)
FROM table
GROUP BY `P3`, `P2`,`P1`;
```

Comment: Severe overengineering on the second example.  All you have to do is pretend that you are not using a database that allows you to mismatch the select and group by clauses.

Comment: You have lost me but I am intrigued. Can you expand on your comment?

Comment: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression COUNT(DISTINCT `P3`)

Comment: I wrote it before I took a closer look at the desired output.  Now I don't understand the question.

Comment: I can't see an error with it. Which query are you getting the error with? Can you post your table declares and a few sample line of data, along with what you want output to go with that data?

Comment: Your query that fails doesn't have all the columns that are not in the aggregate (count) function in the GROUP BY clause. The DISTINCT at the start is irrelevant (the GROUP BY will do that anyway). Having DISTINCT within the COUNT will group all the unique values of P3, but you are also bringing back the value of P3 so it can only ever be 1. I have modified my answer with a 3rd query that does what I think you want.